# Capturing clicks in a column of buttons (with dojo)

Tags: button, kendo-ui, grid, click

I am trying to capture the click event of a row using a column of "use" buttons. This is similar to the "selectable" feature in the Kendo grid, but having a button makes it more obvious for the user in our case.

Because there are multiple buttons (and I don't know if you can dynamically assign button id values), I tied a CSS class to the button, and I will use that to determine what row I am on when the user clicks the USE button.

Here is a dojo of what I am trying to accomplish, but for some reason, the click event (alert statement) is never executed.

http://dojo.telerik.com/UkIW/2

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you're using jQuery and no Dojo code so far. But there are some mistakes here, first of all, you should put the event handler for hte buttons in the `ready()` handler as well, so move it inside:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...
});
```

And then second, if you're binding to dynamic elements with jQuery, the preferred way of doing so is by adding it to a parent element (for example the `<body>`) and then adding a second parameter as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...
  $("body").on("click", ".use", function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

I created a milestone in your example: http://dojo.telerik.com/UkIW/5